# Angular HttpClient http.put => HttpResponse is null. Call Succeeded, No error in Console, Have Tried returning 204 instead of 200

Tags: angular, httpclient, httpresponse

After hours of googling, I've found a few people describing similar issues; although many were seeing a json parse error.

But when this is called:

```
return this.http.put(url, json, {headers: this.jsonHeaders, observe: "response" });
```

the subscribe for it

```
.subscribe((res) => {...});
```

has a null res. So i can't check res.status; which would be pretty handy for a put.

Has anyone seen and overcome this?

Comment: Have you tried logging the error as well by also subscribing to the error? If res is null, i guess there might be an error which doesn't show in the console.
`.subscribe((res)=>{...},(err)=>{...})

Comment: Puts don't require any result to be posted back, which is probably what's happening here.  The idea is that the put is IDEMPOTENT and it either works or it doesn't.  200 would me it worked, anything else requires investigation. If I were you I'd look at the server side code handling the request.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that while, at least for my scenario, the  'observe: "response"' option is also critical, it was an issue with an interceptor that was apparently correctly returning error responses, and the body of a response, but otherwise what made it to the subscriber was null.